# Loading external URL using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I load external webpage's part into a DIV using jQuery? According to similar questions's answers I tried in the below manner but it didn't work for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(document).ready(function(){
          var _url = 'http://www.campaignmonitor.com/templates/#galleryThumbs';
          $('#mbody').attr('src',_url);
});
</script>
<div id="mdody"></div>
```

Please do not recommend iframes. Its not possible to retrieve only a portion of an external page to my iframe. I just need only a DIV portion of external page to be viewed in my page.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: Are you looking to use an iframe? Or load a block of html into a div?

Comment: @quoo - I want to retrieve external website's HTML content (Not full page just a portion) into my DIV.

Answer (score 0):

you can't retrieve html from a cross-origin location unless the other domain supports CORS.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var resturl = "http://example.com";

$.ajax({
  url: resturl,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data){
   $("#mdody").html(data);      
  }
});
```

Comment: This code is connecting browser with website but page is not being displayed in my DIV :(